# dropdown box with entry

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have a list of some entries I want to sort the entries by entering some keyword.

```
from tkinter import *
from ttkwidgets.autocomplete import AutocompleteCombobox

root = Tk()
root.geometry("100x100")

Phone_no = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant"]
new_list = []


def selected_list(event):
    match = [i for i in Phone_no if entry.get() in i]
    print(match)
    new_list.clear()

    # this for add data to the listbox
    for c in match:
        new_list.append(c)

    entry.config(completevalues=new_list)


def printer(event):
    print(entry.get())


entry = AutocompleteCombobox(root, width=15, font=('Times', 10), completevalues=Phone_no)
entry.place(x=10, y=10)

print_button = Button(root, text="Print")
print_button.bind("<Button-1>", printer)
print_button.place(x=10, y=20)


# Execute Tkinter
root.mainloop()
```

after the keyrelease the list was not updating and selectlist method is not calling ,
how to fix , advance thanks

Comment: You want `Autocomplete` but also sort the list?

Comment: yes for getting list in selected data

Comment: Then call `sort()` method of list?